# WiFi turning on when I have it turned off

Tags: macos, wifi

On my Mac (2014 MacBook Pro running Yosemite) I turn the WiFi off at work. We have WiFi, and Ethernet, and I find the Ethernet faster.

Every once in a while, I see that it turns itself on, searches for a WiFi connection, and then turn itself off.

The whole thing happens in about four seconds. The WiFi icon on the menu bar will show WiFi on, and trying to connect (to our corporate hotspot), then the WiFi Off icon will show.

I get the following errors in Console:

```
2/10/15 4:02:31.765 PM airportd[35]: _handleLinkEvent: Got an error trying to query WiFi for power. Resetting state variables.

2/10/15 4:02:31.792 PM locationd[61]: wifi scan failed with error: Error Domain=com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error Code=-3903 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error error -3903.)"

2/10/15 4:02:31.796 PM airportd[35]: -[CWXPCConnection performScanWithChannels:ssidList:legacyScanSSID:includeHiddenNetworks:mergeScanResults:maxAge:maxMissCount:maxWakeCount:maxAutoJoinCount:interfaceName:waitForWiFi:waitForBluetooth:token:priority:reply:]: !!! SCAN request received 1.2115 seconds after previous scan request from 61 (locationd)  

2/10/15 4:02:31.800 PM locationd[61]: wifi scan failed with error: Error Domain=com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error Code=-3903 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.wifi.apple80211API.error error -3903.)" 

2/10/15 4:22:30.940 PM WiFiAgent[577]: [EAPOLControl.c:180] EAPOLControlAuthInfoIsValid(): Ignoring SaveCredentialsOnSuccessfulAuthentication since no credentials were specified  

2/10/15 4:22:32.735 PM airportd[35]: _handleLinkEvent: Got an error trying to query WiFi for power. Resetting state variables.
```

Seems to happen once every 20 to 30 minutes. I'm not closing the lid. I have WiFi turned off. The company doesn't use Airport.

Comment: From parsing the log, it looks as if some process is trying to set the laptop's location via a wifi connection. Go to System Preferences > Network > Wifi > Advanced ... button and delete all the preferred networks that you don't actively use. If there are several networks in the list you **do** wish to keep, drag the one you connect to most frequently to the top of the list. You might alternatively just zap the whole list of preferred networks and start fresh. BTW/ fully updated Yosemite? (10.10.2)

Comment: @IconDaemon So this is just my Mac trying to figure out where it is? This is then part of _Location Services_ then. Right? Come to think of it, when I used my Mac at home today, the WiFi was on, and when I take it to work after using it at home, I don't usually have to turn it off. Yes, I am on 10.10.2. Thanks for asking. And, I did clean up my Wifi network list. I also shut off automatically adding WiFi networks. I had a few "Free WiFi" networks in that list.

Comment: It could also be part of Location Services, found in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy tab > Location Services. If none of the apps listed, (if there are any apps listed to begin with,) are checked, then click the Details... button next to System Services and see what is selected there. I had Spotlight Suggestions checked. If there are apps that require Location Services, determine whether you really need them to use the service. Your Mac may be trying to ascertain its location, but for some reason the wired connection @work may disallow this, so it falls back to Wifi. A guess.